# Blender to Unity. Particle Settings

Tags: particles, export, import, unity

I modeled a realistic flower in Blender. The flower itself isn't very complicated but the middle is very hairy with hundreds of stamens. I modeled one stamen and multiplied it using Particle Settings with render as object. The question is how to bring it to Unity properly?

If I convert it into mesh the model weighs 35 MB which is not good I guess.

[image]

Comment: Hi this platform is for Blender related questions and issues. Your question is how to bring it to Unity. Maybe try posting on https://answers.unity.com/ :)

Answer (score 0):

1000 Stamen is quite a lot, are you sure you need that many in Unity to make it look good? 
There are some solutions: 
 
Ignore the 35MB, let Unity optimize it. That would be np if there are no other objects in the scene 
make sure the stems have as few vertices as possible and reduce their number. 
If the stem source object(s) have modifiers on them either remove or apply them, that way Blender should create instanced meshes, which Unity understands 
If you are fine with coding, export one stamen and replicate it in Unity.
 FBX is usually the best format to exchange 3D models, it can handle instances, carefully check the export settings (choose export and where you are supposed to state the file location, press n). You don't need any import settings to support instances, but also go through the options of the fbx import in Unity, there's often stuff you can customize to fit your specific situation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! You mentioned 'instanced meshes'. Which way of import should I use to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend 2 things:

1. Bring your particle count to around 200-500. 1000 is quite a bit for this sort of thing!
2. In the mesh's **modifier properties panel**, click `Make Instances Real`. Then, click on **one** of the instances, then right-click, and click `Join`. Now the instances are all one mesh.